# Why does this nested jquery UI sortable double the event and shows 2 placeholders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the example on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lhx7Y/

The column divider is suppose to split the columns into two equal parts which are by themselves sortables. So one could drag the text module in any of the columns or into nested splited columns

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you hover over with your droppable it has the original behind it, so they both are being "hovered" and so both show a placeholder.

If you drop another column splitter, you get three on the hover etc.